# Execution of single elements in grid.arrange / general functionality of grid.arrange (gridExtra)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, gridextra, grob

I have a general question about the functionality of `grid.arrange` (`gridExtra`) and possible improvement potentials. Using an R Shiny app, I display various outputs (`ggplot2`, `textgrob`, `rasterGrob`) via a `grid.arrange`. During execution, however, data changes, making it necessary to update individual elements. But executing the whole `grid.arrange` takes a lot of time.

Is there a more streamlined way to avoid calculating the whole `grid.arrange` each time a single objects changes? Or to implement my problem in a different way? Is it perhaps possible to "cache" the individual elements to then speed up the output when one object is changed? The implementation by `grid.arrange` was necessary so far to align the different objects perfectly, but ~10 seconds waiting time is very long.

I am grateful for any advice!